# GWT adding widget to Column Header

Tags: gwt

I want to customize my cell table's column header. I have to include support for sorting and filtering. I want to have images for both actions. When the user clicks on the sort image, it will toggle (based on ascending / descending order sort ) and the table sorts based on the icon clicked. I am currenty doing this with some messy HTML manipulation , in the onBrowserEvent of my custom header cell. Could someone tell me how I could use GWT's ToggleButton here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use GWT Widget in Cell Table.
But, you can use a custom Cell for the header.

```
public class ButtonHeader extends Header<String> {
  private String text;

  /**
   * Construct a new TextHeader.
   *
   * @param text the header text as a String
   */
  public ButtonHeader(String text) {
    super(new ButtonCell());
    this.text = text;
    setUpdater(new ValueUpdater<String>() {
      @Override
      public void update(String value) {
        //When the button is press
      }
    });
  }


  @Override
  public String getValue() {
    return text;
  }
}
```

You can change this for use an other Cell for your usage.

Answer (score 0):

For a (not-so) complete documentation on custom cells [check this link](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html).

You WILL have to override onBrowserEvent(), even if it's clumsy, since you can't use a GWT widget in a cell but **you can render it**. Yet, it'll lose all it's event handling capabilities.

([from this post](http://mpickell.com/blog/2013/01/28/widgets-in-gwt-cell-tables/)) Widgets are never attached to the DOM. They exist to be manipulated in memory and then have their HTML extracted and pushed into the DOM. Events from the Widgets, therefore, are not handled. Cell events ARE handled.

So you could just use `widget.getElement.getInnerHTML()` to render the widget you want in your header (a toggle button or anything else). Despite having this option at hand, my advice would be to use your own SafeHtmlTemplates instead of using `getInnerHTML()`.